# Django image rotation

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using django-smartfields to resize uploaded images to save to my model. It works great, except if the original image is in portrait orientation the image gets rotated 90 degrees clockwise. It doesn't rotate landscape images. I can't find much in the documentation to figure out how to change this behavior. I want it to preserve the original orientation and resize it as-is.
Here is my model:

```
from smartfields import fields
from smartfields.dependencies import FileDependency
from smartfields.processors import ImageProcessor

class Image(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, blank=True)
    image = fields.ImageField(upload_to = settings.MEDIA_URL, dependencies=[ 
      FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
        format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 500, 'max_height': 500}))
    ])
```

And here is the handler:

```
def create_image(request):
    form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        client = Client.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
        image = Image.objects.create(client=client, 
        image=form.cleaned_data['image'], pet_name=request.POST['pet_name']
```

Comment: Are you sure the image doesn't have rotation metadata (e.g. EXIF orientation in a JPEG)?

Comment: oh shoot you're right, i didn't know that was a thing! Time to figure out how to strip exif. THanks!

Comment: @KristaP I'm experiencing the same problem.  How did you solve this>

Comment: Unfortunately that is indeed a problem with EXIF and there has been a long standing ticket for that issue: https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields/issues/3